# How to set locale?

Tags: locale, perl

After a clean Ubuntu Server install, I get the following error when running 'perl'.

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_CA.utf8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Where should I set my locale, system wide and user specific? If there's a command line utility to do it I'd rather use it than manually edit configuration files.

Comment: Related: [How do I fix my locale issue?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162391/62483)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Type the following in terminal to get rid of that error,

`sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`