# installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: 12.04, package-management, locale

I am constantly receiving updates but when I download then, in the end it gives the error message package operation failed. I am not able to figure out what has caused this exactly. I don't have enough reputation else I would have posted the screenshots!
I have a total disk of 18Gigs, out of which 10Gigs is free.
I tried few methods like following:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But it still gives the error message and it's irritating.

Thanking in advance.

The whole error message is:

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up firefox (28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing firefox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up openjdk-7-jdk (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing openjdk-7-jdk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.10) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing samba-common-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up ssh-askpass-gnome (1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.2) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing ssh-askpass-gnome (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
<br>
<b><i>Errors were encountered while processing:<br>
 firefox<br>
 openjdk-7-jdk<br>
 samba-common-bin<br>
 ssh-askpass-gnome</i></b><br>
Error in function: 
Setting up ssh-askpass-gnome (1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.2) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing ssh-askpass-gnome (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:3.6.3-2ubuntu2.10) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing samba-common-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up firefox (28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing firefox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/17001/how-to-set-locale

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message:

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

It seems that you have a problem with **locale** (human language support). You have your language defined as `LANG="en_IN.ISO8859-1"`, but `dpkg -L locale|grep en_IN` shows only
`/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_IN`

So, try something like:

```
bash
export LANG="en_IN"  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
exit
```

as a workaround. If you want a log, you can replace the `bash` command with `script my.log`

As for how you ended up with `LANG="en_IN.ISO8859-1"`, I am puzzled.

Reading on,

```
Setting up firefox (28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac': Not a directory
dpkg: error processing firefox (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

Says that, while `dpkg` was trying to `--configure` the `firefox` package, a subprocess failed (`status 2`), probably because it could not find `/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javac`. but since this is the **second** major error in this logfile, it might have been caused by the **first** error. If it happens again, after fixing the `LANG` problem, worry about it then.

```
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
```

`apport` is the error-reporting system. You have had so many errors (more than `MaxReports`), that `apport` did not send this error to Canonical/Ubuntu Support (see `man -k apport`).

Just read, and understand, the messages. Fix the first problem and any independant-looking other problems. Lather, Rinse, Repeat.

`