# Command to compare two strings

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to compare two strings and ignoring the case of the contents.
IF [ $first != $second ]. Anything I can add to this command so that the comparison ignores the case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In bash, you can perform case conversions easily e.g. if `var="vAlUe"` then

```
$ echo "${var^^}"
VALUE
```

while

```
$ echo "${var,,}"
value
```

You can use this to make you comparison case-insensitive by converting both arguments to the same case, i.e.

```
if [ "${first,,}" == "${second,,}" ]; then
  echo "equal"
fi
```

or

```
if [ "${first^^}" == "${second^^}" ]; then
  echo "equal"
fi
```

---

Another approach is to use the bash `nocasematch` option (thanks @Tshilidzi_Mudau), although this appears to work only with the `[[ ... ]]` extended test operator:

```
$ first=abc; second=ABC
$ (shopt -s nocasematch; if [[ "$first" == "$second" ]]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No match"; fi)
Match
```

but

```
$ (shopt -s nocasematch; if [ "$first" == "$second" ]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No match"; fi)
No match
~$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not recognize letters with diacritical marks: `é` is not converted into `É` (or vice versa).

Comment: Is your locale define for the correct (with diacritics) letters, @G-Man? (http://askubuntu.com/questions/17001/how-to-set-locale)

Comment: @boardrider: Well, (a) my default locale is en_US.UTF-8, (b) I'm not willing to make non-volatile configuration changes (even if reversible) or install software on my machine just to test this, and (c) I'm doing this on Cygwin, which might not be 100% representative of Unix.  But (1) even in the en_US.UTF-8 locale, I can do `var="àÉîö"` and `echo "$var"`, and it correctly regurgitates the characters that I gave it, and (2) I started a new shell with `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 bash`, and "${var^^}" and "${var,,}" still just give me `àÉîö`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And I believe that I have effectively set bash’s locale, because (a) when I type `type foo`, it says `bash: type: foo : non trouvé`, and (b) `env | grep LC_` and `set | grep LC_` give no output.  Can you suggest anything else to try?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84942/how-to-convert-utf-8-txt-files-to-all-uppercase-in-bash might be helpful.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': The locale *fr_FR.UTF-8* must exist. Otherwise, it may fall back to *C* this creates the behavior you describe.