# Microsoft Lync on Kubuntu + problem with Pidgin-sipe

Tags: pidgin

I'm new to this forum, but I follow it already since a time on Internet. But now I have a question I couldn't find a ready-made answer for.

I've been convoked to a team meeting via Microsoft Lync web app, but that application is incompatible with Linux. The first page shamelessly says "you can optimise your experience if using a compatible operating system and browser", which is another wording for "Linux users not admitted".

So I browsed the Internet and found that apparently you can worm your way in using Pidgin-SIPE. I installed it with the help of another user (there was a problem with the locale, which he helped me to resolve), BUT how to proceed for getting to Lync?

Thanks already A LOT for any help you can provide!

Best regards,

Eva

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set locale?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17001/how-to-set-locale)